# How to find the value count from multiple columns

Tags: hive

Can someone help me in pulling the gender count from below sample data

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goTAf.png)

O/P can be :

M 18
F 11

or

M F
18 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 'M',
       sum(case when col1='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col2='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col3='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col4='M' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col5='M' then 1 end) as m_cnt,
       'F',
       sum(case when col1='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col2='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col3='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col4='F' then 1 end)+
       sum(case when col5='F' then 1 end) as f_cnt
  from your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. 
In case if I want to find an average of 'M' and 'F' values, what should be the syntax?

O/P should be something like 
M  67% F 32%

Comment: @Chethan  total (100%) is number of rows * number of cols = 30 in your example. total = `count(*)*5`, right? then m_pct=m_cnt*100/total;  m_cnt=18. 18*100/30=60%

Comment: Thanks for the syntax, Valeriy.

What to do when there are N number of rows. Is there a way to find the average without  using number of rows * number of cols in a single command, just like the above one. Eliminating the null values! but only selecting all the 'F' and 'M' values from the required columns?

Comment: @Chethan  The number of colunns anyway should be known in advance, it is not dynamic. If you want to find total count of not NULL:  count(col1)+count(col2)...+count(col6) = total, and sums by M and F values are calculated in the answer. Just combine them in the upper subquery using expression for percent calculation. The number of rows does not matter. I believe you asking about N columns, right? Columns shoul be provided in the query. And yes, it is single SQL statement ofcourse

Comment: I still could not figure out to find the average. I'm not thinking right.

Comment: @Inban Create question with code and data example, including desired output (do not use pictures !) and me or someone else will definitely help. If you will keep posting pictures, it will only attract downvotes